# How to keep the data moving from development to production DB: Rails3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dev-to-production

Boys and girls,

So, I have finished my Rails3 webapp and I am trying to deploy it. Am using Passenger, I have managed to configure it as to point to the rails app, that is fine.

Now, since in development i have made of course changes to the app and I want to deploy it with the data i have imported until now. I tried to "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production, but the data are lost! Even the users I have created while developing are lost and need to create them again...

Isn't there any way to keep the data while moving from development to production environments?

Thank you very so much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I have used the [yaml_db gem](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db) to do export from one environments db to another and it's worked great.

That said, running migrations shouldn't cause all your data to disappear.  Is your db being destroyed and then re-created or is it actually emptying the tables?  Also, how are you deploying the app to production - using capistrano?  If so check that there are no unwanted extra tasks being run as part of the deployment

Comment: Well for the time being (is my first deployment), I have just copied the directory structure to the production server, made a 'bundle install' to install missing/required gems and then 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production'..and then comes the problem...

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood slightly - it sounds like the data was never in the production db to begin with. The contents of your dev db are not transferred by copying the rails app - the idea is that you have 2 separate dbs for development and production so that the dev one can be filled with rubbish data whilst you are testing without polluting your production environment.  If you want to transfer data from your dev db to production, use the yaml_db gem.  I would also strongly recommend setting up capistrano anyway as it's pretty painless and makes the deployment process nice and easy.